# Creating field dependency is preventing me from editing/clicking into Opportunity fields

Tags: picklist, validation-rule, dependent-picklist, field-dependencies

My question regards field dependencies. I am trying to limit my picklist based on the stage of an opportunity. I have that part down, but after I create it and go into an opportunity, I am unable to click into or edit any of the fields. As soon as I delete the field dependency, the issue goes away. Why would that be?

Here is a picture of the dependency configuration: 
[image]

Comment: Hi Ben, the more specific you are, the better we can help you. In this case, perhaps some screenshots of your configuration would be best.

Comment: Hi Adrian - Thanks for the response. I've added a screenshot of the config